# ckeditor set textarea value

Tags: php, javascript, json, ckeditor

I can't get the correct value from the textarea

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="cmscontent" id="cmscontent"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('cmscontent');
</script>
```

I'm using a JSON request to send it to the server, and the `$_POST['cmscontent']` value stays empty all the time. Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: It would be helpful to see how you pass a JSON request. Otherwise, there is nothing that may prevent you from retrieving the CKEditor data via `$_POST['cmscontent']`, regarding normal POST requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `editor.updateElement()` before you send AJAX request saving content. This method will update the textarea element with contents of the editor.

You can get the `editor` instance from `CKEDITOR.replace()` or from instances object - `CKEDITOR.instances.cmscontent`.